# Can I pause/resume a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I'm using Docker Desktop for Windows (Linux container mode) to run a batch job involving advanced wave acoustics simulations and precomputation for game development. On my AMD 3950x (16 cores 32 threads), the work takes about 11 days. Problem is, I use the computer for other work too (small indie studio using computer for personal stuff after work hours).

So I would like pause the work so I can use the computer for other stuff, then resume it later. Is this possible? I'm on latest Docker Desktop for Windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm on latest Docker Desktop for Windows.

Nov. 2021: with the latest Docker Desktop (including for Windows), you no longer have to pause/unpause each container one by one:

> ### Docker Desktop 4.2 Release: Save Your Battery with Pause / Resume,
>
> With Docker Desktop 4.2 we’re excited to introduce Pause / Resume as well as a host of changes to make it easier for you to manage updates.
> These features are available to Docker Desktop users on any subscription tier.
>
> #### Save your battery with Pause / Resume
>
> Pause / Resume gives developers the power to pause their current Docker Desktop session and resume work whenever they want, **saving resources on their machine while Docker is paused**.
>
> When you pause Docker Desktop, the current state of your containers is saved in memory and all processes are frozen. This lowers CPU usage and will help with saving your laptop’s battery life. To resume Docker Desktop, click either the Resume button in the menu or type any Docker CLI command in your terminal.
>
> To try out this feature on Docker Desktop 4.2, navigate to the whale menu and click the ‘Pause’ button.
> The corresponding content sections for Docker Desktop’s left sidebar items (e.g. Containers) will then be covered to clearly denote the Pause state.
>
> Please note, Pause / Resume is currently not available in Windows container mod
>
> [image: https://i1.wp.com/www.docker.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2021/11/image.png?resize=1536%2C913&ssl=1]

Source: [Docker Blog](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-4-2-release-save-your-battery-with-pause-resume-and-say-goodbye-to-the-update-pop-up/)

Answer (score 3):

There's `docker pause` and `docker unpause` commands, worth trying them out. I suspect that won't survive reboots, though.

There's also an experimental feature you can enable that will persist to disk: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/checkpoint/.

https://technology.amis.nl/2018/04/08/first-steps-with-docker-checkpoint-to-create-and-restore-snapshots-of-running-containers/ appears to be a tutorial on using this.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [pause](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/pause/) and [unpause](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/unpause/) command. But these are only pausing the process, so they don't survive a restart of the machine.

Probably you want something persistent. For that you have the option between two command sets:

## save/load

With the [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/save/) command you will create a tar archive containing your current state of the container. With [load](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/) you can start that state again. The downside is that all layers of your image will be saved. So potentially this can result in large archives.

## export/import

As an alternative you can use [export](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/export/) which exports the first layer of your container.

> The docker export command does not export the contents of volumes associated with the container. If a volume is mounted on top of an existing directory in the container, docker export will export the contents of the underlying directory, not the contents of the volume.

with import you can create the container again.

The benefit is that you end up with small files and the import is faster since you might have the underlying layers already present on your machine.

---

In both cases you can share the resulting file with other machines and store it in a private repository.
Please also look at the [migration guide](https://docs.docker.com/v17.03/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#backup-restore-or-migrate-data-volumes) for further inspiration.

Comment: Actually pausing is fine, I can always put the machine in sleep of needed. I tried pause and unpause and they worked and the resulting output was not broken and passed checksum tests.

Comment: this is correct - A sleep or hibernate generally at the OS level preserves the memory (RAM) contents. However if you were to pause and then REBOOT (restart) the host, memory is then wiped thus the state of the Docker pause in that memory is wiped as well (it will be lost, and no option to un-pause ,  only the option to re-start the container ).  (at least that is my understanding of it, I have not had a chance to test the pause + host reboot , yet)